# How to get a collection from a linking table Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, fluent

I have a set of tables

Users
UserPermissions
Permissions

A user can have a 1 or many permissions specified by the linking table UserPermissions.

My objects of type User has an IList

I'm not sure how to properly configure NHibernate so that the mapping will look at the UserPermissions key to get the Permission information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

standard many to many mapping?

```
HasManyToMany(user => user.Permissions)
    .Table("UserPermissions")
    .ParentKeyColumn("user_id")
    .ChildKeyColumn("permission_id");
```